# SSIS Script Transformation Error The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, web-services, ssis

I'm using SQL Server and Visual Studio 2019.  I have a SSIS Package that uses a Script Transformation as a source (c#) that pulls data from a web service.  When I execute via Visual Studio on my laptop it all works 100%.  When I deploy to the SSIS Catalog and execute I keep receiving the error:

```
Error The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    string json;
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        
        string fullurl = Variables.FullURL;

        string url = fullurl;

        json = DownloadJson(url);
    }
```

I'm building the url using a variable (fullurl in the above) that includes all the login and password info.  Do I need to modify this or is it something on the company network blocking it?

Comment: Seems the SQL Server account which runs the SSIS package doesn't have access through your company's firewall / proxy server.

Comment: thanks, thought it might be that

Answer (score 0):

the way to authenticate is rarely in the query string. It can be, but usually isn't.

Try this instead...

```
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.Credential = new NetworkCredential([username],[password]);
string json = wc.DownLoadString(url);
```

It is also unusual to do this in the PreExecute portion. You usually do this in the add rows portion of a Script Component source.